# Retornando arquivos XML dentro de uma pasta em PHP

Tags: php, xml

estou usando o seguinte código para listar e ler os arquivos XML nesta pasta. Mas como a listagem me retorna . e o .. meu sistema retorna erro que não e possível acessar esses arquivos. Segue os códigos utilizados.

```
$pasta = $data[0].$data[1].$data[2]."_".$data_end[0].$data_end[1].$data_end[2];
$l_nfe = dir("xml/".$pasta);

while($arquivo = $l_nfe -> read()){
    simplexml_load_file("xml/".$pasta."/".$arquivo);
}
```

A string me retorna "xml/01042018_30042018/.." alguém poderia me ajudar como listar esses arquivos xml e carrega-los para exibir o conteúdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Têm de adicionar execção nesses dois diretorios desta maneira.

```
$pasta = $data[0].$data[1].$data[2]."_".$data_end[0].$data_end[1].$data_end[2];
$l_nfe = dir("xml/".$pasta);

while($arquivo = $l_nfe -> read()){
    if($arquivo !== "." && !$arquivo !== ".."){
       simplexml_load_file("xml/".$pasta."/".$arquivo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado irmão funcionou! Não pensei nessa possibilidade... rsrs